# Comparing single row tables

Tags: sqlite

I have a table named ELZ_A_HS as follows, there are many other columns that aren't included
[image]

One can see that when comparing say 2014-03-01 with 2014-07-08 there occurs a difference in 3_A column. I tried to compare these two rows data via

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM ELZ_A_HS WHERE DATE_ IS '2014-03-01' ) AS T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM ELZ_A_HS WHERE DATE_ IS '2014-07-08') AS T2
ON T2."1_A" = T1."1_A"
```

But above solution doesn't produce proper results, I mean what I require is some kind off differentiation to tell me that on this particular column the data differs...Of coarse the results doesn't necessarily have to be in two columns or one column

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "date" is your primary key. I wrote CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for only part of your table, and I used dummy data. You'll usually get better answers if you include that kind of stuff in your question.

In any case I expect each table expression to return one row. Common table expressions require version 3.8+, I think.

```
with a as (select * from elz_a_hs where date = '2014-03-01')
   , b as (select * from elz_a_hs where date = '2014-07-08')
select a.date, b.date
             , a."1_a" = b."1_a" as "1_a"
             , a."2_a" = b."2_a" as "2_a"
from a, b;
```

```
a.date      b.date      1_a         2_a       
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
2014-03-01  2014-07-08  1           0
```

A 1 in the compared columns means the values were the same; 0 means they were different. (My simplified data doesn't match yours.)